# if/elif/else-statement doesn't work with random.choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
import random
print('hello')
question1 = [' cbca', ' cbbca']



print("What's equal to" + random.choice(question1) + "?")
r = input()
if r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78') and question1 == ' cbca' : 

    print("That's correct!")

elif r in ('1', '1,0') and str(question1) == ' cbbca' :
    print("That's correct!")

else :
    print('r')
```

Whatever the input is, the else statement is always used. Why that?

I know it can't be that hard, but I've just started with this :)

Comment: Any advance on *"breaks"*? Without a [mcve], it's hard to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: i'm sorry, it always goes to else

Comment: Note that you're not actually *storing* the random choice from your list anywhere; and inevitably `str(['cbca', 'cbbca']) != 'cbca'`.

Comment: Check the equality condition you're using  in both `if` and `elif`. Therein lies your answer.

Comment: `question1` is a list and thus can never be equal to `' cbca'` or `' cbbca'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `question1` as a list. Applying `random.choice` on it doesn't change its value, so it is still a list later on. Put the result of `random.choice` in a variable and compare this variable.

```
import random
print('hello')
question1 = [' cbca', ' cbbca']

question = random.choice(question1) # Remember the choice of random

print("What's equal to" + question + "?")
r = input()
if r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78') and question == ' cbca' :

    print("That's correct!")

elif r in ('1', '1,0') and question == ' cbbca' :
    print("That's correct!")

else :
    print('r')
```

Comment: thanks it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You should make that:

if (r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78')) and (question1 == 'cbca') :

Comment: care to explain why?

Comment: Because in start python calculate "r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78')", after it calculate "r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78') and question1", and after "r in ('7,8', '7.8', '78') and question1 == ' cbca'". It is mistake

Comment: This doesn't work, as `question1` is a list, not a string. It doesn't solve OP's question.

Comment: The explanation is also wrong.